# weka gui bug, some content keep blink or disappear in gui

Tags: user-interface, weka

when my mouse move on some content in gui, the content will partly disappear. And the content won't be recovered until I close the weka.
 [image]

My system is windows7*64 with java 1.8 and I have test all the version weka since 3.6 ,they all have such problem for me, while the 3.4 does not.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I am currently running Weka 3.6 and 3.7 on Windows 7 64-bit with Java 1.7, and the application runs fine.

One thing I have noticed from your screenshot is that the font that is used for your layout is different to what I currently use (see below).  Perhaps it has something to do with your default fonts or locale?

[image]